# Remove row if the last one is equal

Tags: pandas

I have this dataframe in Pandas

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01 | 0 |
| 2023-02 | 0 |
| 2023-03 | -1 |
| 2023-04 | -1 |
| 2023-05 | 0 |
| 2023-06 | 0 |
| 2023-07 | -1 |
| 2023-08 | -1 |

I would like to transform it to:

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01 | 0 |
| 2023-03 | -1 |
| 2023-05 | 0 |
| 2023-07 | -1 |

Comment: what happens if more than 2 of same value. remove all except first or remove only last? if keep only first maybe `df[df['value'] != df['value'].shift(1)]`

Answer (score 1):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
out = df[df['value'].ne(df['value'].shift())]
```

Output:

```
      date  value
0  2023-01      0
2  2023-03     -1
4  2023-05      0
6  2023-07     -1
```

Intermediates:

```
      date  value  value_shift     ne
0  2023-01      0          NaN   True
1  2023-02      0          0.0  False
2  2023-03     -1          0.0   True
3  2023-04     -1         -1.0  False
4  2023-05      0         -1.0   True
5  2023-06      0          0.0  False
6  2023-07     -1          0.0   True
7  2023-08     -1         -1.0  False
```